# opensearch security - regex in plugins.security.nodes_dn

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

opensearch-2.11.0

*forum.opensearch.org complains that my question has more than 2 links (WHY) and rejects my question, so I ask here*

Hello, please, help me to configure plugins.security.nodes_dn as regexp. I have 2 node certificates with subjects:

```
Subject: C=CT, ST=City, L=City, O=ORG, OU=admins, CN=node1-elk.org
Subject: C=CT, ST=City, L=City, O=ORG, OU=admins, CN=node2-elk.org
```

I try to set **plugins.security.nodes_dn**  as described in documentation ["Configuring admin certificates"](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/configuration/tls/#configuring-admin-certificates)

```
plugins.security.nodes_dn:
   - '/CN=node[0-9]-elk.org/'
```

But this doesn't work and I get *" Transport client authentication no longer supported"* error like [described here](https://forum.opensearch.org/t/transport-client-authentication-no-longer-supported-error-when-deploying-cluster-with-security-plugin-enabled/9814)

After changing **plugins.security.nodes_dn** to exact list of certs:

```
plugins.security.nodes_dn :
  - 'CN=node1-elk.org,OU=admins,O=ORG,L=City,ST=City,C=CT'
  - 'CN=node2-elk.org,OU=admins,O=ORG,L=City,ST=City,C=CT'
```

everything works fine.

I don't want list every cert for every node and want to use regex, what i'm doing wrong?